# Recovery the missing hour, minute interval MySQL database

Tags: mysql

This is part of my table on MySQL database

```
+----------+---------------------+--------+
| sID      | sDatetime           | sETX   | 
+----------+---------------------+--------+
| 16213404 | 2020-04-24 16:00:00 | 497681 |
| 16213398 | 2020-04-20 14:58:56 | 281011 | 
+----------+---------------------+--------+
```

This table count with 14.121.398 records

I realized that in this case more than one hour has passed between the previous and the next row

```
mysql> SELECT
    TIMEDIFF(
        '2020-04-20 16:00:00',
        '2020-04-20 14:58:56'
    );
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TIMEDIFF(
        '2020-04-20 16:00:00',
        '2020-04-20 14:58:56'
    ) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 01:01:04                                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set
```

this is not possible because the data is downloaded maximum from the source every five minutes

in this case is missing the time slot between 3pm and 4pm

I have tried this query without success because the return is all zero

I think because the sID is not consecutive

The code I've tried below

```
SELECT A.`sID`, A.`sDatetime`, (B.`sDatetime` - A.`sDatetime`) AS timedifference
FROM tbl_2020 A INNER JOIN tbl_2020 B ON B.sID = (A.sID + 1)
ORDER BY A.sID ASC;
```

how can i find this anomaly in mysql table?

my version of MySQL is 5.5.62-log

the name of column is sDatetime the type is Datetime.

any suggestion, please?

thanks in advance for any help

**edit #01**

```
+----------+-----------+---------------------+
| sID      | time_diff | sDatetime           |
+----------+-----------+---------------------+
| 18389322 |       301 | 2020-05-16 23:53:29 |
| 18390472 |       308 | 2020-05-16 23:48:21 |
| 18389544 |       301 | 2020-05-16 23:43:20 |
| 18388687 |       303 | 2020-05-16 23:38:17 |
| 18388398 |       301 | 2020-05-16 23:33:16 |
| 18390451 |       308 | 2020-05-16 23:28:08 |
| 18388915 |       302 | 2020-05-16 23:23:06 |
| 18388208 |       301 | 2020-05-16 23:18:05 |
| 18390516 |       301 | 2020-05-16 23:13:04 |
| 18389904 |       301 | 2020-05-16 23:08:03 |
+----------+-----------+---------------------+

mysql> SELECT
    TIMEDIFF(
        '2020-05-16 23:53:29',
        '2020-05-16 23:48:21'
    ) AS td;
+----------+
| td       |
+----------+
| 00:05:08 |
+----------+
1 row in set
```

Comment: The link I gave in your previous question also has a solution for non consecutive sids. If you mean there is no relationship between sid and sdatetime to the extent that you cannot establish previous and current  then you are stuffed.

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks for reply. I have tried from your link also the suggestion for sID not consecutive. But the error is `[Err] 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Comment: That's a different issue. Does the code work on a small sample?

Comment: @P.Salmon Not working, I have added in sql `LIMIT 10`... and  stopped executing when the time spent is 820 second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this

```
SELECT
    sID
   ,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(@date,sDatetime)) time_diff
   ,@date := sDatetime
   ,sETX
FROM(
SELECT * FROM table1
ORDER BY sDatetime DESC) s1,(SELECT @date :=(SELECT MAX(sDatetime) FROM table1)) s2
HAVING time_diff > 300
```

First you order the table by time, then you get the time difference between two consecutive rows and check if they are bigger than 5 minutes

see example here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2yKt6d5RWngXVYJKPGZL6m/8

Answer (score 0):

Comparing current row to previous works

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(sID  int, sDatetime datetime, sETX int); 
insert into t values
( 16213404 , '2020-04-24 16:00:00' , 497681),
( 16213398 , '2020-04-20 14:58:56' , 281011);

select sid,sdatetime,(select sdatetime from t t1 where t1.sid < t.sid order by t1.sid desc limit 1) prevdt,
         time_to_sec(sdatetime) - time_to_sec((select sdatetime from t t1 where t1.sid < t.sid order by t1.sid desc limit 1)) diff
from t
where  time_to_sec(sdatetime) - time_to_sec((select sdatetime from t t1 where t1.sid < t.sid order by t1.sid desc limit 1)) > 300;

+----------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| sid      | sdatetime           | prevdt              | diff |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| 16213404 | 2020-04-24 16:00:00 | 2020-04-20 14:58:56 | 3664 |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)
```

If this is too slow add your table definition so that we can see the indexes you have.